# Highcharts stream graph - how to make 1:1 scale by Y axis?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is my code - https://jsfiddle.net/rxqpt8u4/1/

```
var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'streamgraph',
        marginBottom: 30,
        zoomType: 'x'
    },


   yAxis: {

        min:0           
    },  
    // Data parsed with olympic-medals.node.js
    series: [
    {
        "name": "Austria",
        "data": [
            2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7
        ]
    }]

});
```

Can't understand why values dont scales 1:1.
Instead of that, they scale 0.5:1.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The axes adapt to the data and they are independent of each other. To have the same scale on the axes set the same `tickInterval`, `max` and `min` properties:

```
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var xAxis = this.xAxis[0];

            this.yAxis[0].update({
                tickInterval: xAxis.tickInterval,
                max: xAxis.dataMax
            });
        }
    }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/289jtzp1/